# How to disable websearch in spotlight on MacOS BigSur

Tags: macos, google-chrome, search-engine, macos-big-sur, spotlight

can anyone tell me how i can disable web search in Spotlight on MacOS BigSur?

I already tried disabling every entry in `Settings -> Spotlight -> Search` but this didn't help at all.

I have Safari, Chrome and Firefox installed and changed the search engine in every browser to something different. When i now use spotlight to for example search after `fusion` and hit enter on the web search, my google chrome opens (default browser) with the search engine selected in safari.

I could not find any setting options regarding this in the safari settings. So is there any way to disable this search option in Spotlight?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: On my Big Sur 11.4, Firefox is my default browser with Duckduckgo as default search in FF.  Spotlight web searches, however, are from Google, which is the default in Safari. Changed Safari default to Ecosia and Spotlight results are now Ecosia (in Firefox). So I can confirm what you suspected - Safari is involved.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about configuring your computer.

Comment: You could probably ask this question at [apple.se].